# Bash command to determine first login for a particular time period

Tags: command-line, bash

Is there a way to determine for example that the current day is the first login for this month? I'm trying to use it in my script. I am familiar with `last` but it does not seem to be the command for this job.

Let's take this for an example:

- If today is first login of the month, echo "first!"
- else echo "nope"

**Sample Scenario:**

July 2 is my first login for the month of July, I logged in 5 times that day. It must only echo "first" on my first login and "nope" on the subsequent 4.

Comment: hi sorry, I accepted it again since it successfully answers the question. However, it did not solve my problem. I have tested the output of `last` right now (Aug 2, first login) but it did not output Aug 2 as the far bottom output  as I have expected so my script did not work as expected.  See my `last` output here (http://imgur.com/brlHP30). Would you suggest another way to determine first login? I ran `last` again just recently and it did output as expected, Aug 2 at the very end however it did not do so in the first time at startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `last` and `awk`

```
last -R "$USER" | \
    perl -ne 'print unless /wtmp\sbegins/ || /^$/' | \
    awk 'END {print $4,$5,$6}'
```

---

`last`  searches  back  through  the file `/var/log/wtmp` (or the file designated by the `-f` flag) and displays a list of all users logged in (and out) since that file was created.

Per default `/var/log/wtmp` is created on every new month:

```
% awk '/\/var\/log\/wtmp/,/}/' /etc/logrotate.conf 
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

`last -R $USER` returns all entries from `/var/log/wtmp` for the given user. The first login is placed at the bottom of the output, therefore the `END` in my `awk` command.

```
% last -R "$USER"   
aboettge pts/1        Wed Jul 15 12:04   still logged in   
aboettge pts/1        Wed Jul 15 11:29 - 12:04  (00:34)    
aboettge pts/1        Wed Jul 15 08:08 - 11:29  (03:21)    
aboettge pts/1        Wed Jul 15 08:08 - 08:08  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Wed Jul 15 08:07 - 08:08  (00:00)    
aboettge tty2         Wed Jul 15 08:03   still logged in   
aboettge pts/1        Tue Jul 14 12:58 - down   (00:53)    
aboettge pts/1        Tue Jul 14 09:06 - 12:58  (03:51)    
aboettge pts/1        Tue Jul 14 09:03 - 09:06  (00:02)    
aboettge pts/1        Tue Jul 14 08:23 - 09:03  (00:40)    
aboettge pts/1        Tue Jul 14 08:22 - 08:23  (00:00)    
aboettge tty2         Tue Jul 14 08:22 - down   (05:28)    
aboettge pts/1        Mon Jul 13 12:01 - 16:26  (04:24)    
aboettge pts/1        Mon Jul 13 11:49 - 11:59  (00:10)    
aboettge pts/1        Mon Jul 13 11:46 - 11:49  (00:02)    
aboettge tty2         Mon Jul 13 11:44 - down   (04:42)    
aboettge pts/2        Mon Jul 13 11:26 - 11:35  (00:08)    
aboettge tty2         Mon Jul 13 11:25 - down   (00:09)    
aboettge pts/3        Fri Jul 10 14:26 - 14:28  (00:01)    
aboettge pts/3        Fri Jul 10 14:23 - 14:26  (00:03)    
aboettge pts/2        Fri Jul 10 13:34 - 15:27  (01:53)    
aboettge pts/2        Fri Jul 10 13:31 - 13:31  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/2        Fri Jul 10 13:25 - 13:30  (00:05)    
aboettge pts/2        Fri Jul 10 10:28 - 13:19  (02:50)    
aboettge pts/1        Fri Jul 10 08:35 - 15:27  (06:52)    
aboettge tty2         Fri Jul 10 08:00 - down   (07:28)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 16:25 - 16:27  (00:01)    
aboettge tty2         Thu Jul  9 16:21 - down   (00:06)    
aboettge tty1         Thu Jul  9 16:03 - crash  (00:00)    
aboettge tty1         Thu Jul  9 15:29 - 16:03  (00:33)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 14:32 - 14:32  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:51 - 08:51  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:51 - 08:51  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:50 - 08:51  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:46 - 08:46  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:46 - 08:46  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:45 - 08:45  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:44 - 08:44  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:42 - 08:42  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:42 - 08:42  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:42 - 08:42  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:41 - 08:41  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:41 - 08:41  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:40 - 08:41  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:39 - 08:39  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:38 - 08:38  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:36 - 08:36  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:36 - 08:36  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:36 - 08:36  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:35 - 08:35  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  9 08:35 - 08:35  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/2        Thu Jul  9 07:50 - 16:03  (08:12)    
aboettge :0           Thu Jul  9 07:50 - crash  (08:13)    
aboettge pts/1        Wed Jul  8 16:13 - 16:27  (00:13)    
aboettge pts/2        Wed Jul  8 13:47 - 16:27  (02:39)    
aboettge pts/1        Wed Jul  8 11:30 - 14:14  (02:44)    
aboettge pts/1        Wed Jul  8 08:18 - 11:29  (03:11)    
aboettge :0           Wed Jul  8 08:02 - crash  (23:47)    
aboettge pts/2        Tue Jul  7 08:54 - 08:55  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Tue Jul  7 08:02 - 13:13  (05:10)    
aboettge :0           Tue Jul  7 07:50 - down   (05:23)    
aboettge pts/1        Mon Jul  6 09:55 - 14:48  (04:53)    
aboettge :0           Mon Jul  6 08:27 - crash  (23:19)    
aboettge pts/2        Fri Jul  3 07:52 - 15:30  (07:38)    
aboettge :0           Fri Jul  3 07:51 - down   (07:40)    
aboettge pts/2        Thu Jul  2 15:16 - 15:18  (00:01)    
aboettge pts/2        Thu Jul  2 15:07 - 15:07  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  2 14:46 - 16:21  (01:35)    
aboettge pts/1        Thu Jul  2 09:53 - 09:53  (00:00)    
aboettge pts/2        Thu Jul  2 08:00 - 14:41  (06:40)    
aboettge :0           Thu Jul  2 08:00 - crash  (23:47)    
aboettge pts/5        Wed Jul  1 14:16 - 14:38  (00:21)    
aboettge pts/3        Wed Jul  1 14:01 - 16:10  (02:09)    
aboettge pts/2        Wed Jul  1 13:27 - 16:10  (02:42)    
aboettge pts/1        Wed Jul  1 13:22 - 16:10  (02:48)    
aboettge :0           Wed Jul  1 13:15 - 16:21  (03:05)    
aboettge pts/2        Wed Jul  1 11:30 - 11:36  (00:06)    
aboettge pts/1        Wed Jul  1 11:29 - 13:02  (01:32)    
aboettge pts/1        Wed Jul  1 11:27 - 11:29  (00:01)    
aboettge pts/2        Wed Jul  1 08:28 - 11:27  (02:58)    

wtmp begins Wed Jul  1 08:28:18 2015
```

---

*Example*

```
% last -R "$USER" | perl -ne 'print unless /wtmp\sbegins/ || /^$/' | awk 'END {print $4,$5,$6}'
Jul 1 08:28
```

*Breakdown*

- `% last -R "$USER"`

  see above
- `perl -ne 'print unless /wtmp\sbegins/ || /^$/'`

  removes empty lines and `wtmp begins …`
- `awk 'END {print $4,$5,$6}'`

  prints the fields 4, 5 and 6 from the last line, the default separator is   (a space)

Comment: up to how many logins does last take record of?

Comment: `last`  searches  back  through  the file `/var/log/wtmp` (or the file designated by the -f flag) and displays a list of all users logged in (and out) since that file was created.

Comment: when i run `last` it does not print logins before the current month(July)

Comment: In your question you talk about "that the current day is the first login for **this month**"

Comment: Yes you got it right, if `/var/log/wtmp` is created every new month,  and `last` just reads it from there then the first login for the month is if `last` displays only 1 entry (or 2? not sure because mine always displays 2 every login). Please confirm if I understood correctly

Comment: I don't understand. `last -R $USER` returns all entries from `/var/log/wtmp` for the given user. The first login is placed on the bottom of the output, therefore the `END` in my `awk` command. If will add an example in my answer…

Comment: Does this mean that next month, if my first login in Aug is Aug 2, that will be the one placed in the end of `last`'s output?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: One last thing: Once I retrieved the last entry in `last`(which is the first for this month). I would know that it is the current log in by checking if it says "still logged in" correct?

Comment: Yes, that's ok to check this with `still logged in`

Comment: In my example, today is the 15. and I'am still logged in. But not for the other dates.

Comment: thanks, now I just have to figure running the script when the user logs in (startup).

Comment: "Yes, that's ok to check this with `still logged in`".  No it isn't, not if there is more than one login at a time.  Additional logins will also be treated as the first of the month, until you log out of the first, e.g. X windows, and tty1.

Comment: @MartinThornton Sure, and where is the problem?

Comment: Pedantic perhaps, but the question states 'It must only echo "first" on my first login and "nope" on the subsequent 4.'  If your first login of the month is still open on tty1, then it would echo "first" on a new login on tty2 as well.

Comment: Can I detect is it the first login since the reboot? @A.B.

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the current `wtmp` log file with `rawtmp`.

First install the tool:

```
sudo apt-get install sac
```

Then use the following command:

```
(rawtmp -s 07/01/15; rawtmp -s 07/01/15 -w /var/log/wtmp.1) \
| grep 'LOGIN Process' | sort | head -n 1 | awk -F: '{print $1}' \
| perl -pe 's/(\d+)/localtime($1)/e'
```

For me it outputs:

```
Wed Jul  1 08:40:58 2015
```

To be sure to get entries for the full month the command calls `rawtmp` two times. The second time using the saved rotation of the logs (`/var/log/wtmp.1`).

`wtmp` rotation settings are managed by `logrotate` and by default on ubuntu they are stored in `/etc/logrotate.conf`:

```
# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

Comment: @krato I've updated my answer to catch logins for the full month (including the 1st day)

Answer (score 0):

```
last <username> | tac | awk '{
    if ( b != $5 && NR !=1 ){
      b=$5; print $4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10
    }
}'
```

This will show first login on every month in `last`.

Here `tac` will reverse the `last` output.

`awk` will show only first occurrence of the new string in column 5 which is first login of a month.

`NR !=1` will eliminate `wtmp begins` line.

Comment: With your command, I have three different lines, eg: `Wed Jul 1 08:28 - 11:27 (02:58)
Jul 9 15:29 - 16:03 (00:33) 
Thu Jul 9 16:21 - down (00:06)`

Comment: I don't know why . But for me this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

An approach not relying on `last` or `/var/log/wtmp`, if the script is run only once just after login, is to create an empty file.  On the next run, if its creation time is earlier than one for the first moment of the current month, or if the file doesn't exist, then `ècho "first!"`.  In either case, update or create the file with `touch` for next time.

```
MONTH=`/bin/tempfile`
touch -d "01 $(date +'%b %y')" "$MONTH"
if [ ~/.lastlogin -ot "$MONTH" ]
then echo "first!"
fi
rm "$MONTH"
touch ~/.lastlogin
```