# Determine if current login is first for the month in Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, login, scripts

This is a continuation of my post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648660/bash-command-to-determine-first-login-for-a-particular-time-period)

Although A.B. provided me with the correct answer, which is by utilizing the output of `last` and checking if it's the current log in, it did not solve my problem. I checked upon login the output of `last` and it did not have the bottom line to be the first login for the month. Instead the first login is on the top (above the logins for July).

I failed to save the screenshot, since as of now `last`'s output erased all of July's. It's like `/var/log/wtmp` did not refresh instantly at login which I expected it to be. Some comments suggested in the part 1 of my post says that it refreshes every first day of the month. Anyway I just want to run some script at startup that tells me if my current login is the first login for the month.

Here is a simple script I wrote:

```
firstLogin=$(last | tail -3 | head -1)

# check if "still logged in" (this is current log in)
if [[ $(grep "still" <<< $firstLogin) ]]; then
    notify-send "first login!!!!"
fi
```

Can anyone suggest a way for this? I would appreciate any help.

EDIT:
As you might have seen in the example script, I'm trying to do it without the help of any temp files. However if there's no other way to do it without temp files I would probably just go with it.

Comment: Just bash or would python do?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'm interested with the Python script but still leaning to Bash.

Comment: OK, I'll wait if it ends in a satisfying way with bash first :)

Comment: A.B. is right that the last line of `last` should be the first login of the month unless you have changed how `/var/log/wtmp` is rotated in `/etc/logrotate.conf` ..alno note that i have said `login` not a session that is continuing from previous day(month)..

Comment: yeah I am pretty sure I did not change anything in `/etc/logrotate.conf`. It is true that `last`'s output gives the first login at the very end but it does not do it immediately after first login

Answer (score 2):

Why not simplify life for yourself and note in a file at each login the current
month, and test its previous value?

When you login and your shell is bash it will read the files
`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`.

So, for example, add to any of these the lines:

```
now=$(date +%m)
last=$(<~/.mylastlogin)
if [ $now != "$last" ]
then notify-send "first login!!!!"
     echo $now >~/.mylastlogin
fi
unset now last
```

---

To avoid the use of a temporary file, you can use any existing file,
eg the ~/.profile file itself.  Just `touch` it at every login after
comparing its `ls -l` time output. Eg:

```
now=$(date +%m)
last=$(ls -ld --time-style=+%m ~/.profile | awk '{print $6}')
if [ $now != "$last" ]
then notify-send "first login!!!!"
     touch ~/.profile
fi
unset now last
```

Comment: If there are no other solutions that doesn't use a temp file I will accept this answer knowing its the only way.

Comment: @krato I've added an alternative which uses the timestamp of an existing file instead.

Answer (score 0):

query the logins for your user only for the current month and count them.

if more than one, you already logged in this month.

oneliner to copy/paste in your terminal:

```
[ $(last -R "$USER" | grep -c $(LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 date +%b)) -gt 1 ] && echo 'nope' || echo 'first login'
```

tested with this output from the `last` command:

```
root     pts/1        Tue Feb 18 13:38   still logged in   
root     pts/1        Tue Feb 18 13:17 - 13:38  (00:20)    
root     pts/0        Tue Feb 18 07:27   still logged in   
root     pts/1        Mon Feb 17 09:29 - 17:08  (07:39)    
root     pts/0        Fri Jan 31 09:50 - 13:54  (04:03)    
root     pts/1        Tue Jan 28 09:19 - 17:11  (07:52)    
root     pts/0        Mon Jan 27 13:58 - 18:01 (3+04:02)   
root     pts/0        Wed Dec 18 11:54 - 12:18  (00:24)    
root     pts/0        Tue Dec 17 17:24 - 19:27  (02:02)    
root     pts/1        Tue Dec 17 16:30 - 16:44  (00:13)
```

or, modifying your sample script:

```
countLogin=$(last -R "$USER" | grep -c $(LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 date +%b))

# check if equals 1
if [ "$countLogin" -eq 1 ] ; then
    notify-send "first login!!!!"
fi
```