# Bash command to determine is it the first ssh connection after the reboot?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

Like the following answer [Bash command to determine first login for a particular time period](https://askubuntu.com/a/648669/660555), instead of for a duration I want to find out to check is the first time the user connected into machine using `ssh`.

Is it possible to find out it a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should print "First" if it's the first login by user "user" since reboot from non-local host:

```
[ $( last | sed '/^reboot/,$d' | egrep '^user +pts/' | wc -l ) -lt 2 ] && echo First
```

Note that the `last` log is usually rotated monthly, so the answer might be incorrect if the user has logged in more than one month ago.
I anchor the expression with `^` to make sure the user name is picked from the first column (should the user's name be *still*, we'd get a false hit on lines reading *still logged in* :-) and I also expect `pts/` to appear, indicating a remote login (local logins are indicated with `tty` instead).

This should work even if the computer hasn't been rebooted current month. But it would not work if your user's login name is verbatim *reboot*.

Comment: Notice that I assume you replace `user` above with the login name of the user you wish to check. If you want a more generic solution replace `user` with either `'$(whoami)'` or `'$LOGNAME'` including the apostrophes. If you still feel it doesn't work, could you please provide the output from your `last` command (replace real names with fake names for security reasons but be consequent).

Comment: People who read this site expect questions to lead to a full and verified answer, not a long debate. Usually these comments are requests for more information, which is expected to be provided. I asked you to provide output, so I could verify my answer, and then add it as an answer for others having the same question. Instead you write "this also works". If you want, you can answer your own question, which can give you credits. I'm out!